# Best approach for determining if an object in reference is null

Tags: javascript, typescript

In JavaScript (or TypeScript), if I'm going to reference something like:

```
return myObj1.myObj2.myObj3.myProperty;
```

to be safe, I guard it with something like:

```
if (myObj1 && myObj2 && myObj3) 
    return myObj1.myObj2.myObj3.myProperty;
else
    return null;
```

Is there a more concise way of just getting null from the above reference without surrounding it by an if?

Please note, since I'll be using this in a TypeScript app, some solutions may not work with dynamic object definition.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you mean `if (myObj1 && myObj1.myObj2 && myObj1.myObj2.myObj3)`?

Comment: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: What if you recursively prints the object is this what you need http://jsbin.com/xuniluqaqa/edit?js,console,output ?

Comment: @Andreas, your link provided a good answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491509/1775513. Add as answer and I'll mark it as such. BTW, any idea if there is a performance degradation accessing a property like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define some temporary objects to substitute when a lookup fails.

```
return (((myObj1||{}).myObj2||{}).myObj3||{}).myProperty || null;
```

You can make a reusable object if desired.

```
const o = Object.create(null);
```

Then use it as needed.

```
return (((myObj1||o).myObj2||o).myObj3||o).myProperty || null;
```

Comment: Looks like a good Javascript solution. I didn't take into account that I might need a Typescript only solution because this gives errors because myObj2 does not exist on o (or {}).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a library like `lodash` for this:

```
 //gets undefined if any part of the path doesn't resolve.
 const answer = _.get(myObj1, "myObj2.myObj3.myProperty");

 //gets null if any part of the path doesn't resolve.
 const answer2 = _.get(myObj1, "myObj2.myObj3.myProperty", null);
```

See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get for details.